How to send messages to multiple devices through FCMusing standard HTTP v1 API send method?
I need to send messages to around 10000 users. SO that I batched the device tokens of 500. I need to send a single messages to 1000 devices on a single shot. Previously I used the legacy method but now its deprecated. I am using laravel11 application.For single device token the blow code works well.
$scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'];

$credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials($scopes, $credentialsPath);
$authToken = $credentials->fetchAuthToken();
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{$projectId}/messages:send";
$headers = [
            'Authorization' => "Bearer {$accessToken}",
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ];
$payload = [
            'message' => [
                'token' => $deviceToken,
                'notification' => [
                    'title' => "Test Alert22",
                    'body' => "This is a test message",
                ],
                'data' => [ // Ensure this is a map (key-value pairs)
                    'key1' => 'value1',
                    'key2' => 'value2',
                ],
            ],
        ];

  $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($url, $payload);

How can I send to multiple devices where device tokens are stored in an array.
